# How to programatically count DBF records?

Tags: java, visual-foxpro, dbf

I am trying to verify that the record count in the Visual FoxPro DBF header matches the physical count of records in the DBF itself. The point of this exercise is to create a "poor-man's" utility to fix one of the "Not a table." problems.

My code seems to be very close, but I'm obviously not reading the correct file sentinel for "this is the last record".

So, what my code does is it goes to the first record offset in the file. Then it counts how many times it can advance by the record length before getting a -1 back from the read() (Java RandomAccessFile).

It seems that checking for -1 is just returning the EOF character, but not the "This is the last record" character, whatever that is. So, there appears to be additional bytes beyond the last physical DBF record I'm reading and that's throwing off my record count.

So, I'm wondering, having come up empty looking at DBF documentation, how do I know when I've iterated to the last DBF record offset in the file?

I can post my code, but I'm not sure it would be helpful.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: May I ask why you have to this with Java? Maybe there is another way than manually parsing it. For instance, there is a (good enough) Python module for dbf files. I'm assuming that Visual-FoxPro itself is not an option for you, right?

Comment: I'm not aware of a last record character. Are you including the deletion marker in your record size?

Comment: As I noted above, I'm trying to create a small utility for the "Not a Table" problem. The Python module you indicated is quite good, but AFAIK, it's not a utility to fix DBF problems. Thanks.

Comment: As noted, here, the length of a record is in header bytes: "10 - 11  Length of one data record, including delete flag".  https://www.dbf2002.com/dbf-file-format.html. I am matching what the Python program reports for record length. My offset into the first record is the header length + 1 byte.